# Xcode 4.2 Switching File Shown in Editor

Tags: xcode

When I run my code, Xcode switches from the file I was working on to main.m in the editor.  It's driving me nuts.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any runtime errors? Any time i've seen this. the execution is pausing due to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or similar deathly error

Comment: This has nothing to do with crashes. It has to do with Xcode's behaviour settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your menu bar at the top select

Xcode --> Behaviours --> Edit Behaviours

then select Show Navigator --> Current View

and

Show Debugger --> Current Views

Do this on any category that you feel may be triggering this behaviour.

Comment: In retrospect, I may have made a slight error on this. I think you only need to set one of these. Like Show Debugger. Either way, playing around with these functions should produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

like @Robotnik said, it sounds like you are crashing out for some reason.  Look at the Console of your app within XCode and see if there are any exceptions or errors being thrown there?

And if that doesn't work, set breakpoints and step through your code and see what line might be causing the app to abort.

Crashes are usually the only reason I've ever seen for XCode to "magically" browse to main.m.

Comment: No, it's not crashing, it's running fine.  It just switches the editor over to main.m every time.